# QT regex display the full text instead of what is asked

Tags: c++, regex, qt, gps

i'm having an issue with my regex here where i'm trying to get the longitude of a gps data and instead it's giving me the entire coordinate

my code

```
QRegularExpression GPSLong("((?<=,\\s)([0-9](.*?)+(W|E)))");


 while (!file.atEnd()) 
{
    QString line = file.readLine();
    i++;

    QRegularExpressionMatch matchGPSLong = GPSLong.match(line);

    if ( matchGPSLong.hasMatch()) 
    {
        QString GPSLongCoordinates = matchGPSLong.captured(0);
        qDebug()<< "Longitude : " <<GPSLongCoordinates;
    }
  //....
}
```

An example `line` is

> 43° 31' 8.3" N, 5° 3' 13.2" E, 0m

And the result I'm getting is

> Longitude : 43° 31' 8.3" N, 5° 3' 13.2" E

But I was expecting

> Longitude : 5° 3' 13.2" E

i'm using Qt 5.9.2 on Windows10 and can't update to a newer version because of the software i'm working on

**EDIT** : i managed to find a solution, instead of getting DMS(Degrees, Minute, Second) coordinates i switched to DD (Decimal Degrees) and then used global match to obtain a `QRegularExpressionMatchIterator`

here's the fixed and working code :

```
QRegularExpression GPSRegex("-|[0-9]+\\.+[0-9]+");


while (!file.atEnd()) {
    QString line = file.readLine();
    i++;

    QRegularExpressionMatch matchGPSLat = GPSRegex.match(line);
    auto matchIterator = CoordinateRegex.globalMatch(line);

    if (matchGPSLat.hasMatch()) {

        QString GPSLatCoordinates = matchGPSLat.captured(0);
        while(matchIterator.hasNext())
        {
            auto result = matchIterator.next();
            if (!matchIterator.hasNext())
            {

                GPSLongCoordinates = result.captured(0);
            }
        }

        double GPSlat = GPSLatCoordinates.toDouble();
        double GPSLong = GPSLongCoordinates.toDouble();
    }
}
```

Comment: `line` seems to be a bit ambiguous here. There seems to be a `line` right before the start of your code snippet and there's another one within the `while`-loop. And is the file-reading at all relevant or...?

Comment: The code posted above is in a Slot and there's nothing above the `GPSLong`, and as for the while there's 3 more regex which are working fine.
The file reading isn't that relevant just put it here to show why it's used...

Comment: Err... so how is `line` defined in `QRegularExpressionMatch matchGPSLong = GPSLong.match(line);`?

Comment: My bad i misplaced it and didn't even see, thanks

Comment: May help if you tell us what OS/Qt Version you're using. Me hard-coding `QString line = "43° 31' 8.3\" N, 5° 3' 13.2\" E, 0m";` and looping through match captures gives me 3 `"5° 3' 13.2\" E"`, 1 `""`, 1 `"E"`.

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
QString GPSLongCoordinates = matchGPSLong.captured(1);
```

instead of:

```
QString GPSLongCoordinates = matchGPSLong.captured(0);
```

The 0-index of a capture is the entire match.  If any groups match, those groups starting at index 1 are the respective matches.

Comment: capture 0 is the whole match rather than the whole line (unless the regex matches the whole line)

Comment: @KyleRoss index 0 through 2 still give me : `Longitude :  "43? 31' 8.3\" N, 5? 3' 13.2\" E"`
index 3 is " " and 4 "E" as expected